# Missing argument label in

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on some smileys in Swift using UIBezierPath.
The following functions are called within a class - consequently considered as methods.
The function "getEyeCenter" which is called by the "pathForEye" requires "eye: eye" as input argument. I can't understand why. In my opinion, "eye" should be sufficient?!

When I change it to "eye: eye" in Swift, there's an error in the next line, requiring "pathForCircleCenteredAtPoint(midPoint: eyeCenter,...) ".
Why does the program require this syntax for the first argument of the function?

```
private enum Eye {
case Left
case Right
}   
 private func getEyeCenter (eye:Eye) -> CGPoint
{
    let eyeOffset = skullRadius / Ratios.SkullRadiusToEyeOffset
    var eyeCenter = skullCenter
    eyeCenter.y -= eyeOffset
    switch eye {
    case .Left: eyeCenter.x -= eyeOffset
    case .Right: eyeCenter.x += eyeOffset
}
    return eyeCenter
}

private func pathForEye (eye: Eye) -> UIBezierPath
{
    let eyeRadius = skullRadius / Ratios.SkullRadiusToEyeRadius
    let eyeCenter = getEyeCenter(eye) // **here Swift wants "eye: eye "** 
    return pathForCircleCenteredAtPoint(eyeCenter, withRadius: eyeRadius)
}
```

I hope someone has an explanation/solution to my problem.

Thanks, Lukas

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of Swift.

- In Swift **2** the first parameter label is **omitted**.
- In Swift **3** the first parameter label is **required**.

Answer (score 0):

As vadian says, this changed in Swift 3.

I'm going to ignore Swift 2 since it has been replaced with Swift 3 for new development.

functions have both an internal and external parameter name.

By default a function uses the same name for both the internal and external parameter name. So:

```
private func getEyeCenter (eye:Eye) -> CGPoint
```

Is the same as

```
private func getEyeCenter (eye eye:Eye) -> CGPoint
```

If you want to be able to call it using

`getEyeCenter(myEye)` instead of `getEyeCenter(eye: myEye)` then you need to 
declare it with an empty external parameter name:

```
private func getEyeCenter (_ eye:Eye) -> CGPoint
```